# Pending (incomplete transaction)

Tags: paypal, pending

I have a CiviCRM event linked on my web site, and one person tried to purchase tickets to the event several times.  She says she was eventually able to log into her PayPal and complete the transaction.

Our receipts go into our PayPal account, and her payment is not showing up in our account.  In addition, her transactions all show as 'Pending (incomplete transaction)' in the CiviCRM event.

In reviewing previous posts, it appears that there is an issue with how PayPal processes payments, but the discussion and the patch is WAY over my head.

Can anyone give me a simplified answer to how to get her last transaction to process properly?  I'm very concerned that this will become a larger issue with others attempting to purchase tickets.

Thanks!

Comment: Rebecca did you face this problem recently?

Comment: Yes.  The transactions were attempted on April 9, and again today, when she says they went through at her end.  But all show as pending/incomplete.

Comment: Can you confirm if it was working before and then it stopped suddenly?

Comment: The last successful transaction from the event was ta April 8, 2019 at 7:35:06 AM PDT.

Comment: So that means something got changed after April 8,2019 7:36 am. Can you check if the paypal payment processor setting is using live credentials in CiviCRM? Was there any transaction made after 9th of April 2019?

Comment: You don't say which payment processor you using for PayPal. There are three alternatives. And also which version of CiviCRM. My experience is that we get the Pending (incomplete transaction) quite often, but on investigation it has always been that someone is not confident with PayPal and they have not completed. Have they checked that the transaction shows on their PayPal account, not just that they thought it completed.

Comment: Pradeep, 

I don't know how to check if the paypal payment processor setting is using live credentials in CiviCRM.

No successful transactions after April 8.

Comment: Mick,

I don't know how to determine which processor, nor which version of CiviCRM.  It is provided through my web host, OneEach.

I have not asked the buyer for more details, because she is one of our Board members, and I am trying to tread lightly with her and this issue.  But I will do so.

Comment: When I go into admin settings, it says I don't have permission to view the payment processors.